# Android GPS distance Calculation

Tags: android, gps, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between multiple GPS destinations.

> My Approach

I am using Google's Matrix API for this, but it allows at max. 25 points. And I need to track the complete distance travelled by a user.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Post your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am sending this request,

Comment: Google distance matrix returns the driving distance between two points but not the distance between them. That being said if you hold premium account with Google you can request 625 elements per call ( 1000 elements per second) which allows you to have 25 X 25 origins and destinations or 1 X 625.

Answer (score 1):

Using Android SDK:

Try using the Location object's `distanceTo` function like so:

```
float getTripDistance(List<LatLng> vertices) {
    float totalDistance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size() - 1; i++) {
        Location tLoc1 = new Location("");
        Location tLoc2 = new Location("");

        tLoc1.setLatitude(vertices.get(i).latitude);
        tLoc1.setLongitude(vertices.get(i).longitude);

        tLoc2.setLatitude(vertices.get(i + 1).latitude);
        tLoc2.setLongitude(vertices.get(i + 1).longitude);

        totalDistance += tLoc1.distanceTo(tLoc2);
    }

    return totalDistance;
}
```

You can loop over all of your points sequentially and sum each respective distance **in meters** to get the total trip distance.

Comment: It works but , does it give the distance same like Google does?

Comment: I don't work for Google and I didn't help develop Android, so I really can't tell you that. Here's the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)  If the answer worked as a solution for you, mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late but this is for users who are still searching for a solution.

```
float[] distanceResults = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
        newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, distanceResults);
```

As per documentation, the above function computes the approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them. Hence, the variable `distanceResults` will have the distance in meters.